# How to synchronize files differing only in xattr

Tags: rsync, synchronization, xattr

I am using `rsync` to synchronize my files but I have come to a problem when in source I add some tags (or in general probably modify xattrs) to the file, no other changes and it seems that this does not change the modified date of the file. Therefore, `rsync` is unaware that it should copy the file over. Further, the hashes are also the same. So is there a way to keep synchronized files the attributes of which are different?

At this moment I am using:

```
rsync --dry-run -vhzrXte ssh user@server:dir1/dir2/dir3 dir1/dir2/dir3
```

but if I change e.g. tags of some files in `dir3`, the files do not get synced, apparently, the modified date/time is the same and so seems to be the size.

Comment: Provide your full rsync command. Normally using rsync -AX will pickup xattr changes + this will only work if xattr support exists at both source + target of your rsync operation. For example, if you rsync -AX from Linux to OSX, then your xattr changes will be a NOP (no operation/zero action), because OSX has no concept of xattrs.

Comment: @DavidFavor I am syncing between to almost identical Debian distributions (both at 9.2) both supporting xattr.

Comment: I find that `rsync` does transfer the changes, but claims the file is up to date with `-vv`

Comment: With 3 `-v`s (and no `--dry-run`), the only difference in output between a case where there has been a change in attrs and one with no change is a `set modtime of file.test to (1510757291) Wed Nov 15 14:48:11 2017` line (even though the modtime has not changed). I see no difference at all with `--dry-run`. Looks like a bug to me (was between 3.1.2 client and 3.1.0 server)

Comment: Hi guys! How did that turn out eventually? My application: macOS 11 Big Sur syncing a directory with large video files to a NAS running OpenMediaVault with EXT file system. When sighting the videos I give them Finder flags ("good take", "good but secondary", "delete at will", etc). In some syncs my metadata (xattrs `com.apple.FinderInfo`and
`com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags`) is the only thing that changed. For that cases the Finder tags should sync over reliably. Works perfect with locally attached disks. But not with the rsync on Linux. Versions and built flags in followup comment(s).

Comment: Extra or different capabilities of macOS version emphasized:

`macOS 11:` rsync version 3.1.3  protocol version 31 Capabilities: 64-bit files, 64-bit inums, **64-bit timestamps**, 64-bit long ints, socketpairs, hardlinks, symlinks, IPv6, batchfiles, inplace, append, ACLs, xattrs, iconv, symtimes, **no prealloc**, **file-flags**.


`OpenMediaVault 5:` rsync version 3.1.3  protocol version 31. Capabilities: 64-bit files, 64-bit inums, 32-bit timestamps, 64-bit long ints, socketpairs, hardlinks, symlinks, IPv6, batchfiles, inplace, append, ACLs, xattrs, iconv, symtimes, prealloc.